# Want to return 0 in the integer list IF SUM(something) is null

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

So, I am using Room in Java in Android.

I am returing the list of payment from the database like this

```
"SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payment), 0) FROM works_db_table WHERE account_year = :year " +
" GROUP BY account_month ORDER BY account_month
```

But, it returns nothing if the payment of certain month is 0. For instance, if payment for month 1 is 200, payment for month 2 is 0, and payment for month 3 is 100,
it will return **[200, 100], not [200, 0, 100).**

I have tried with IFNULL, but happens the same.

The answer of @forpas fixed this, but his code has some errors. The code below is slightly modified version of his code-

```
  SELECT Ifnull(Sum(w.payment), 0)
FROM   (SELECT 1 month
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 9
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 10
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 11
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 12) m
       LEFT JOIN works_db_table w
              ON w.account_month = m.month
                 AND w.account_year = :year
GROUP  BY m.month
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a query that returns all the months 1-12 and then `LEFT` join it to the table:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(w.payment), 0) 
FROM (
  SELECT 1 month UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
  SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
) m LEFT JOIN works_db_table w
ON w.account_month =  m.month AND w.account_year = :year 
GROUP BY m.month
```

Comment: Wow, your answer is correct. It worked. But I needed to add UNION ALL in some places, where they are missing.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy for humans to infer that there's a month missing, but as the data technically doesn't exist the database doesn't know that it should be there. The solution is to create "**Filler**" months/dates with no payments against them.

**(Disclaimer**: I found this on another forum, but I can't find it now. There are a bunch of ways to do this though )

I'm not super familiar with **Room**, but in **SQL server** I use this query:

```
-- Set the start date of the data
DECLARE @DateFrom date = CAST('2020-01-01' as date);

-- Set the end date of the data
DECLARE @DateTo date = CAST('2020-12-31' as date);

-- Generate a table with one entry per month
WITH DateRanges AS
(
    SELECT @DateFrom AS 'DateValue'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DateValue)
    FROM DateRanges
    WHERE DateValue < @DateTo
)

select
    *
from
    DateRanges
```

Just union your existing data to the "**DateRanges**" CTE and it will fill in the gaps

Comment: Thanks, man, for your answer. Your answer is too long, and I thought the other answer is more applicable in Room db.